# Copy data activity failing when entering the table name dynamically in sink dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

[image]

Following this [MS article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/copying-azure-table-storage-using-azure-data-factory-adf/ba-p/3062401), I have created the following steps:

**Step 1**: **Added the New Pipeline with two parameters with names as sourceSAS and destinationSAS and given their SAS tokens as values**

[image]

Step 2: **Created the Web activity and Named as ListTables**:

| URL | @concat('https://srcstorage789.table.core.windows.net/Tables', pipeline().parameters.sourceSAS) |
| --- | --- |
| Method | GET |
| Headers | Accept - application/json |

**Step 3**: **ForEach activity**:

| Items | @activity('ListTables').outputValue |
| --- | --- |

**Step 4**: **Web Activity - Named as CreateTable** - This is created inside the ForEach activity

| URL | @concat('https://deststorage789.table.core.windows.net/Tables', pipeline().parameters.destinationSAS) |
| Method | Post |
| Body | @json(concat('{"TableName":"', item().TableName,'"}')) |

Content-Type    application/json
x-ms-date       @utcNow()
x-ms-version    2021-02-12
Accept          application/json

**Step 5: Create Copy Data Activity - Here I didn't understand the article clearly is whether to create the datasets directly or create the Copy Data Activity.**

How do I specify the table name dynamically so that it will take all tables from source storage:

[image]

How to give the value of the table field so that all source storage tables should be copied to destination table storage account?

[image]

***Whereas I tried giving the specific table name in both of the datasets in CopyData Activity, it copied successfully but unable to copy all the tables at a time from source to destination storage account..!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify multiple tables dynamically, you need to use **dataset parameters**.

Create a string parameter in your dataset like below.

[image]

Now, click the **Enter manually** checkbox in the dataset and select dynamic content at the table name. Give the created parameter name like below in that.

[image]

Now, inside the ForEach, add the dataset to the copy activity and it will show the same parameter. Here, you need to add your table name `@item().TableName` dynamic expression like below. For sample, I have taken lookup activity.

[image]

**If you want to specify the target table dynamically, you need to do the same for the target datasets as well**.

Execute the pipeline and it will give the expected results like below.

[image]

Comment: Do i want to link Copy data activity with the for each activity?

Comment: Inside For each activity, you need to use copy activity with your source and target datasets where parameters are created.